# Combining Regular Expression <br/><img/><p/>

Tags: regex

I have 3 regular expressions:

```
<(?!img\s*\/?)[^>]+>
<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>
<(?!p\s*\/?)[^>]+>
```

which are stripping everything apart from these 3 tags. How to combine them into one?

So I would like to strip all html apart from `<img>`, `<br>` and `<p>` and also white space into always one space.

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried already to solve this problem, what problems are you running into? Before asking a question here at stackoverflow, you should try work it out yourself, then if you still cannot solve your problem, come here but also add what you have tried and what problems you are running into.

Comment: I have tried this <(?!img\s*\/?)[^>]+>|<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>|<(?!p\s*\/?)[^>]+> also this <(?!img\s*\/?)|(?!br\s*\/?)|(?!p\s*\/?)[^>]+>

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  They stand alone.  Combining `regular` and `expression` does not mean the same thing as the single tag `regular-expression`, which is shortened here on SO to just `regex`.  Please tag with care and make sure to read the tag summaries that appear when you start typing tags in the box.

Comment: Also, you should not be using regexes to attempt to parse HTML.  Please find an HTML parsing library for your language of choice and use it instead.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this

```
<(?!(img|br|p)\s*\/?)[^>]+>
```

but consider using html parsing library. This approach is really bad